# How long does a bonus last?

Tags: core-worlds

In core worlds, there are several ways to give bonus ground strength to Infantry. For example there is a Cyborg who gives +1 Ground strength to each Infantry that attacks with him.
If I use my Medi-bot to save my now 2 strength grunt, how long does that +1 strength last? Until the end of the invasion? Until the end of the round? End of the game?

Answer (score 2):

**Till the end of the current invasion.** Cyborg reads:

> During an invasion involving the Cyborg, you may spend 1 Energy to add +1 Ground Strength **to every Infantry Unit in that invasion**.

The [rule book](http://www.quixoticgames.com/coreworlds/coreworlds_official_rulebook4.pdf) defines an Invasion as:

> Invasion: In order to add new worlds to his Empire, a player must launch Invasions. A player performs an Invasion **by discarding enough cards from his Warzone** to match the Fleet Strength and Ground Strength of the World he is invading.

So, the saved Ground Unit will only get the +1 bonus during the current invasion (cyborg's rules text). The Med-bot can save the troop from being discarded, but the bonus ends immediately after the current Invasion that Cyborg is participating in.